# A different name for BLE (bluetooth) for a different iDevice?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have this very very strange issue with BLE.

We have some BLE hardware that had a previous name called "x" .
Than we have changed that device name to be "y" .(long time ago)

When we run the app on the iPhone 6 ,we discover the device in the name "y" as it should be.

When we run the app on the iPad, we discover the device in the name "x" !

How can this happen ?

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"%@",peripheral); //different names !
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the same device is stored on your old device. And when you try to discover it, the iPad gets the name from Stored data and do not ask it from remote(other device) to share it.

While when on the other iPAD, when it tries to find the device, it asks for the name from the other device.

Now if you change the name of hardware again to Z, the old iPADS will show names like X, Y. And new device will show new name as Z. :)

Solution can be >> try removing old devices from the paired devices list on your iPAS and find them again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that iOS caches the `name` of `CBPeripheral`. It often won't refresh until the iOS device is restarted. 
As a workaround, you can get the most recent name in the `advertisementData` dictionary under `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` [key](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Advertisement_Data_Retrieval_Keys).